# How to fix "some packages could not be installed ... unmet dependencies" installing Java?

Tags: java, openjdk

I have some problems downloading with the `sudo apt-get` command.

I try to get Java runtime:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree   

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  openjdk-6-jre : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: ttf-dejavu-extra but it is not installable
                 Recommends: icedtea-netx but it is not installable
```

Can someone help me, I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing. In the command line type in `software-center` now search for java. That should fix all your problems.

Also I recomend installing synaptic as your package manager to assist you with individual packages.

Comment: Details: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

openjdk-6-jre: Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.10.1) but 6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.10.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu7 is to be installed
               Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:2.1-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
               Depends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Tried to install synaptic through softwarecenter didn't work aswell. also some packet problems..

Comment: sudo apt-get clean will fix any broken packages. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade will force install any packages that won't install. Also check in the software center do you have any kinds of java installed that can prevent other kinds of java packages from installing? That can be found in the installed section. Remove if you do. Your issue might be misplaced repository list or broken packages.